# Add sense of (geo) orientation to object (Android)

Tags: android, orientation

Interesting problem (IMHO) here. This is an Android based question btw.

Let's say I have an object, a square. This square has a length & width.

The square is drawn to the device screen.

I want to be able to draw an arrow (or some other indicator) on the screen which shows the user which way East is, in relation to the onscreen square.

Edit:

Attempting to re-phrase the question to make it clearer:

Lets assume a square's 'walls' are numbered 1-4 from left, clockwise.

I want to be able to pick up from the device, that my user is walking East. Therefore if I assign East 'on the square' to mean towards the 'right' (ie. wall 3) then I can indicate to the user that they're walking towards wall 3 (perhaps by highlighting that wall.

Similarly, if 'North' is assigned as wall 4 (ie. the bottom wall) and a user walks South, then they'll be heading towards the 'top' wall (ie. wall 2).

Hopefully that helps......

Comment: `...in relation to the onscreen square`?

Comment: Yes. Like... http://imgur.com/OSbRFQr

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: "east in relation to the onscreen square" is not enough.  Do you mean east assuming that the top of the square is north, or magnetic east, without reference to the orientation of the square?  Or geographic east (and if so, using what kind of projection) etc etc.

Comment: Attempted to clarify the situation. See edit.

Comment: I think that simplifies the situation.  You want to indicate the magnetic direction of movement of the device relative to the square you draw where the top of the square represents north.  However, I still do not see a question.

Comment: How do I 'assign' a magnetic direction to my shape?

Comment: Ah, OK.  See the Compass demo app in the SDK samples.  It has everything you need.